# need some advice in setting up my first server

Tags: linux, system-installation

**Questions**

1. Should a GUI be installed on a server?
2. Are solid state drives a good option for Virtualizations? How can I use SSD for
   virtualization?

*conditional information:*
I apreciate advice that follows the standards for working and administrating linux.
This is a private project, so theres no boss or special laws we have to consider.

**Should a GUI be installed on a server?**

Now i thought about taking Debian as root system, since it is the one i worked most. Would you guys send me to hell for installing a GUI.. you know.. for keeping things easy? Or lets say if i can't handle the terminal ninja moves, it might be a plan B to have the GUI. (for example configuring a virtual maschine (Virtualbox)).
*Is there some way to install a GUI but only execute it when necessary? Would this be reccommended?*

**Are solid state drives a good option for Virtualizations? How can I use SSD for virtualization?**

I have 1 SSD's and servals HHD, so my thought was to use the SSD for the "Virtual Maschine Drives" to get the most possible efficency.

**Can you evaluate how my hardware will preform from the perspective of acting as a virtualization-server?**

Here is the list of the components

Coolermaster, Cooler Master HAF XB RC-902XB-KWN1 Midi-Tower - schwarz
http://www.mylemon.at/artikel/coolermaster/rc_902xb_kwn1/geh-haf-xb-cube-rc.html
AMD, AMD FX-8120 3100 AM3+ BOX
http://www.mylemon.at/artikel/amd/fd8120frgubox/fx-8120-prozessor-eight-core.html
MSI, 760GA-P43 (FX) AM3+ AMD760 ATX
http://www.mylemon.at/artikel/msi/7699_010r/mb-760ga-p43-fx-760.html
Geil, GeIL Dragon RAM Series DDR3-1600, CL11 - 16 GB Kit
http://www.mylemon.at/artikel/geil/gd316gb1600c11dc/d316gb-1600-11-dragonram-k2.html
Noctua, Noctua NH-U9B SE2 CPU-Kühler - 2x92mm
http://www.mylemon.at/artikel/noctua/nh_u9b_se2/kue-combo-nh-u9b-se2.html
Aerocool, Aerocool GT Series Netzteil, 80Plus Bronze - 500 Watt
http://www.mylemon.at/artikel/aerocool/en53976/gt-500-500w-atx.html
SNT, Wechselrahmen 3-in-2 SATA/SAS black OEM
http://www.mylemon.at/artikel/snt/jj_2131_sata/wechselrahmen-3-in-2-sata.html

Comment: **You need to ask specific questions.**  And yes, listing the components does seem irrelevant -- it verges on spam, in fact.

Comment: There are serval specific questions in this post..

Comment: No. There's sort of one regarding GUI use, but that makes most of the other chaff extraneous, hence *lacking specificity*.  Stack Exchange is intended for questions that can be answered in such a way that the answers will be useful to *other people too*.  So you ask a question someone else might what to read, such as **Should I install a GUI on a Server?** (= a good question).  Otherwise, everyone and their uncle will come on with posts like "I need advice setting up a server" and we end up repeating the same things in slightly different configurations over and over.

Comment: @derty I've attempted to edit your question to make it a little more appropriate, there is still a lot of work that needs to be done, when and *if* it passes peer review, look it over and modify it to reflect more what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @Mallow thanks for the edit but multiple questions should be separate. Also, I'm not sure the OP was actually asking all the questions you extracted from their post.

Comment: I will rewrite this questions so that it will be conform with the wished guidelines. Or at least it will be nearer to what is wished. Just give me some minutes!

Comment: @terdon Totally Agree, I hope it will help guide the OP. ^_^

Comment: So i took out some questions and did this structure thing. I know its still not very specific as you would like to have it, but it now it should be usefull for other users that might have the similar question. Maybe chaing the title and adding some tags would even improove it? Thank you for your help guys, take some appreciation

Comment: @Derty, please [don't combine multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/203101). Your first two questions are answerable but should be split into two posts since they are not related. Your question about the hardware is off topic (see [help/dont-ask]) since it will be more a matter of opinion than solid fact.

Comment: @terdon Allright, i split it then! And the hardware question is not about my or your opinion, i'd like to know what advantages or disatvantages i have by this hardware. Of course i did some research and had some thoughts when i desiced, it would help me lern when somebody evalute it.

Comment: @derty no one can advise you unless we know exactly what the server will be used for, how many users it will have, what kind of load you expect, what kind of network it will be a part of etc etc.

Comment: Derty, I'm sorry if this wasn't clear before: what we mean by splitting it into specific questions is that you ask each question *separately*.  This is different than a forum or a mail list, where there is a continuous evolving thread.  Have a look here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/asking and consider what **->a<-** question is.  Something that might as well be titled *"2 or 3 questions related to linux servers, or 1 linux question and 1 or 2 server or hardware related questions"* is no good. Also: doing a *bit* of research yourself helps tremendously.  Search, read, and *reference it*.

Comment: anyways, thank you guys for the advise, i got a little bit of what i wanted and lernt a lot of how to use stackexchange right :)

Answer (score 2):

### Replacement for GUI

Using a web based Configuration Panel will save you a lot of grief. This is a replacement to the GUI, you won't need the GUI with this, but you can install a GUI on your test run. [You will start over from scratch at least twice if you've never done this before]

Cpanel and Virtualmin (and I guess Plesk?) are popular options.

For a quick start I recommend Virtualmin (for it's ease of use, but there is a learning curve if you've never done any of this before)

Virtualmin Website: 
http://www.virtualmin.com/

Easy way to install Virtualmin: (Untested as I don't have a debian box in my work environment)

```
apt-get install wget
wget http://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/scripts/install.sh
chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

[**I leave it to you to read the documentation.**](http://www.virtualmin.com/documentation)

Answer (score 0):

At first avoid installing GUI on server, it's dangerous for a server.

Then for a mail server, it's better you use `postfix+dovecot` for your server:

```
apt-get install postfix postfix-mysql dovecot dovecot-mysql dovecot-pop3 dovecot-imap
```

Then configure them.
To become root use :

```
sudo su
```

You don't need install many webservers, you should install apache as weberserver and configure it as `Name-base Virtualhost` See google for its documentation. you can find easily:[ubuntu and apache name-base](https://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Configure_apache_to_use_virtual_hosts_on_ubuntu_server)

Notes: dovecot has 2 versions, *dovecot* and *dovecot2*. if you are finding doc, use dovecot2.

Comment: thanks mohsen, we're 3 guys and everybody gets his own developmentserver(webserver). What is so dangerous about installing GUI on a server?

Comment: It's not dangerous per se, but if you want to be totally paranoid, adding any software that you don't absolutely have to use adds security risks.  So by that line of thought, you should go through `/usr/bin` and delete anything you think is unnecessary -- just kidding.  Don't do that.  My point is you don't have to be that paranoid, but it is worth considering.

Comment: @derty: A secure system does what it's intended to do _and nothing more_. (A good quality system does what it's intended to do. I don't remember where I saw those definitions, but they're good ones.)

Comment: @goldilocks: a sensible variation of your "going through `/usr/bin`" is going through all set[ug]id programs.

Comment: @ninjalj : Point taken!  You obviously shouldn't literally delete them from `/usr/bin` either, you should remove them as packages using the package manager.